# Escape curly brackets in Jquery template literal

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var fname = 'pic.jpg';

`<div class='col-md-2 mb-2 posr'>\
     <input type='checkbox' class='custom-control-input chk pos-ab'>\
     <img src="{% static '${fname}' %}" class='img-thumbnail'>\
 </div>`
```

Above code prints this in console:

```
<div class='col-md-2 mb-2 posr'><input type='checkbox' class='custom-control-input chk pos-ab'><img src="/static/%24%7Bfname%7D" class='img-thumbnail'></div>
```

Which means `${fname}` not being evaluated as a variable because of the `{%`. How to escape the curly bases around % so that they are not evaluated and `${fname}` is evaluated?

**Edit** added snippet to demonstrate what it is doing in javascript

```js
var fname = 'pic.jpg';

console.log(`<div class='col-md-2 mb-2 posr'>\
     <input type='checkbox' class='custom-control-input chk pos-ab'>\
     <img src="{% static '${fname}' %}" class='img-thumbnail'>\
 </div>`);
```

Comment: `src="{% static 'pic.jpg' %}"` this is what it logs in console - do you want it like this in console logs `src="/static/pic.jpg"`?

Comment: I am not getting that in console (or in html). the ${fname} is not resolving at all, its being treated literally. I want the first expression what you wrote. ${fname} is getting evaluated if I remove { and } in the src. I read in the template documentation that ${fname} wont get evaluated because its inside another pair of curly brackets (which I want to escape but dont know how to)

Comment: Is this question about the jQuery [Template Plug-In](https://github.com/KanbanSolutions/jquery-tmpl) that was last updated 9 years ago?

Comment: @Yogi no its not. Its about Jquery template literals. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: I've added a snippet to so we can all see what it's doing.  It's not doing what you say it's doing.  Is your code elsewhere?  Such as server-side?  Are `{%` from [tag:django]?  Please update the snippet to *demonstrate* the issue.  See [mcve].

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks for the snippet. I am surprised its running ok here but not in my app. This code is present in a django template. I am fetching a list of pics from server side and trying to populate the `#grid`. For me the `fname` variable is not resolving at all.

Comment: u should investigate whats the actual value of fname... ! :-) maybe your django stuff requires to escape the single quotes in  `"{% static '${fname}' %}"` this could be a way to invetigate too

Comment: @johnSmith If I remove the outer brackets (near %) and run the same code, `fname` is interpreted correctly and is printing the file name to console. Those outer brackets are a part of django template syntax and it is interfering with Jquery template literal's interpretation of curly brackets.

Comment: But you are aware that javascript might have a completely different context than django templating? are you running this javascript on a server to generate templates? or do you run it in some kind of browser?

Comment: @johnSmith I am running this in a browser. I am generating this html and doing `$('#grid').append(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this.

In place of:

```
<img src="{% static '${fname}' %}" class='img-thumbnail'>
```

Use this:

```
<img src="static/${fname}" class='img-thumbnail'>
```